# Generate create scripts to a DB Project using msbuild

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, database-project

I wanted to generate a DB project of an SQL Server database programmatically. I'm able to build a database project using the msbuild command line.

Is it possible to generate create scripts for all objects in a database (SQL Server) to a database project using msbuild command line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd probably find it easier to use SQLPackage than MSBuild.  However, you'll need a "target" to generate scripts and that will likely end up being a Create Database and all objects type script.